Sendlog query is giving me only one records while there are lot of sent emails through various journeys
The query below is my Sendlog query however it gives me only one records, which makes nonsense as there are lot of other records should be popped up as emails were sent through various journeys. Can you guys please check the query if there is anything wrong with it. Thank you.
SELECT  socc.[SubscriberKey]                                                as 'ContactKey',
            socc.[JobId]                                                        as 'JobId',
            socc.[Domain]                                                       as 'Domain',
            socc.[ListID]                                                       as 'ListID', 
            socc.[BatchID]                                                      as 'BatchID',        
            'TRUE'                                                              as 'Sent',
            j.[EmailName]                                                       as 'MessageName',
            j.[EmailSubject]                                                    as 'Subject',
            j.[EmailID]                                                         as 'AssetId',    
            format(socc.[EmailSentDate]
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'SentDate', 
            (CASE WHEN socc.[EmailOpenUnique] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END )                                           as 'Opened',
            format(socc.[EmailOpenDate]
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'OpenedDate', 
            (CASE WHEN socc.[EmailClickUnique] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END )                                           as 'Clicked',
            format(socc.[EmailClickDate]
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'ClickedDate',
            (CASE WHEN socc.[SpamComplaint] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END)                                            as 'SpamComplaint',
            format(socc.[SpamComplaintDate]
                     AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'SpamComplaintDate',
            (CASE WHEN socc.[FTAFUnique] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END)                                            as 'Fowarded',
            format(socc.[FTAFDate]
                     AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'FowardedDate',
            (CASE WHEN socc.[Unsubscribed] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END)                                            as 'Unsubscribed',
            format(socc.[UnsubscribedDate]
                     AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'UnsubscribedDate',
            (CASE WHEN socc.[Bounced] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
                    ELSE 'TRUE' END)                                            as 'Bounced',
            format(socc.[BouncedDate]
                     AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'BouncedDate',        
            socc.[BounceType]                                                   as 'BounceType',
            socc.[BounceDetail]                                                 as 'BounceDetail',
            socc.[Delivered]                                                    as 'Delivered',
            (CASE WHEN  socc.[Delivered] = 'False' THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                   ELSE 'FALSE' END)            as 'Undelivered',
            JR.JourneyName                                                      as 'JourneyName', 
            JR.JourneyID                                                        as 'JourneyID',
            JR.VersionNumber                                                    as 'JourneyVersion',
            JA.ActivityID                                                       as 'ActivityID',
            JA.ActivityName                                                     as 'ActivityName',
            format(GETDATE()
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'
                    AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')     as 'LastModifiedDate',
            JR.VersionID                                                        as 'JourneyVersionID',
            'Email'                                                             as 'ContactChannel',
            
            ssl.EmailAddress                                                    as 'Email',
            LEFT(JR.JourneyName, 6)    AS 'CampaignCode',
         SUBSTRING(JR.JourneyName, 7, CHARINDEX('_', JR.JourneyName, 7) - 7) AS 'CampaignName'
    
    
    FROM    (SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.SubscriberKey, s.JobID ORDER BY s.BatchID DESC) as Row_Num, 
                        s.AccountID, 
                        s.OYBAccountID, 
                        s.JobID, 
                        s.ListID, 
                        s.BatchID, 
                        s.SubscriberID, 
                        s.SubscriberKey, 
                        s.EventDate as 'EmailSentDate', 
                        o.EventDate as 'EmailOpenDate', 
                        c.EventDate as 'EmailClickDate', 
                        s.Domain, 
                        s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, 
                        s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey,
                        o.IsUnique as 'EmailOpenUnique',
                        c.IsUnique as 'EmailClickUnique',
                        cp.[IsUnique] as 'SpamComplaint',
                        cp.[EventDate] as 'SpamComplaintDate',
                        f.[IsUnique] as 'FTAFUnique',
                        f.[TransactionTime] as 'FTAFDate',
                        u.[IsUnique] as 'Unsubscribed',
                        u.[EventDate] as 'UnsubscribedDate',
                        b.[BounceCategory] as 'BounceType',
                        b.[BounceSubcategory] as 'BounceDetail',
                        b.[IsUnique] as 'Bounced',
                        b.[EventDate] as 'BouncedDate',
                        (CASE WHEN b.[IsUnique] IS NOT NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END) as 'Delivered'
            FROM       [_Sent] s
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_Open] o 
                    ON s.[JobID] = o.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = o.[SubscriberKey] AND o.[IsUnique] = 1 
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_Click] c 
                    ON s.[JobID] = c.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = c.[SubscriberKey] AND c.[IsUnique] = 1
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_Unsubscribe] u
                    ON s.[JobID] = u.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = u.[SubscriberKey] AND u.[IsUnique] = 1
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_Complaint] cp
                    ON s.[JobID] = cp.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = cp.[SubscriberKey] AND cp.[IsUnique] = 1
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_FTAF] f
                    ON s.[JobID] = f.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = f.[SubscriberKey] AND f.[IsUnique] = 1 
                FULL OUTER JOIN [_Bounce] b
                     ON s.[JobID] = b.[JobID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = b.[SubscriberKey] AND b.[IsUnique] = 1    
                ) AS socc
        JOIN [_Job] j
            ON socc.[JobID] = j.[JobID]    
        JOIN [_JourneyActivity] JA
             ON socc.[TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID] = JA.[JourneyActivityObjectID]
        JOIN [_Journey] JR
            ON JA.[VersionID] = JR.[VersionID]
        LEFT JOIN ent._ListSubscribers as ssl
            ON socc.[SubscriberKey] = ssl.[SubscriberKey] /* AND ssl.ListID = '65' */
       
    WHERE   socc.[Row_Num] = 1
            AND LEN(socc.[SubscriberKey]) = 18
           
      /*       AND (socc.[EmailSentDate] AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time'))))   
            AND (socc.[EmailSentDate] AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time') < DATEADD(hour, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time'))))  */


What are the primary key fields of the target data extension?

You need to be careful to understand the relationships between the data views and the types of joins that you use to connect them.  Including the Journey data views introduces another one-to-many relationship beyond the send job to activity (send, open, click).
When you combine all of these together into a single query I'd suggest thinking about the target data extension schema and the primary key combination that indicates uniqueness.
Here's how I'd approach your query.  Outer apply is like a left join with the criteria inside.  This type of join makes it easier to aggregate for use in the outer queries.  I'll let you add back in the date localization:
SELECT
  s.AccountID
, s.OYBAccountID
, s.JobID
, s.ListID
, s.BatchID
, s.SubscriberID
, 1 as Sent
, s.EventDate as EmailSentDate
, s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey

, j.EmailName as MessageName
, j.EmailSubject as Subject
, j.EmailID as AssetId

, jr.JourneyName
, jr.JourneyID
, jr.VersionNumber
, jr.VersionID
, jr.ActivityID
, jr.ActivityName

, sub.SubscriberKey as ContactKey
, sub.EmailAddress as Email
, sub.[Domain]

, CASE WHEN o.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Opened
, o.EventDate as OpenedDate

, CASE WHEN c.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Clicked
, c.eventDate as ClickedDate

, CASE WHEN cmpl.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as SpamComplaint
, cmpl.eventDate as SpamComplaintDate

, CASE WHEN f.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Fowarded
, f.TransactionTime as FowardedDate

, CASE WHEN u.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Unsubscribed
, u.eventDate as UnsubscribedDate

, CASE WHEN b.IsUnique is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Bounced
, CASE WHEN b.IsUnique IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Delivered
, b.eventDate as BouncedDate
, b.BounceCategory as BounceType
, b.BounceSubcategory as BounceDetail

, case
    when jr.journeyName is not null then left(jr.JourneyName, 6)
  end as CampaignCode
, case
    when jr.journeyName is not null then substring(jr.JourneyName, 7, charindex('_', jr.JourneyName, 7) - 7)
  end as CampaignName

, GETDATE() as LastModifiedDate
, 'Email' as ContactChannel

FROM _Sent as s
INNER JOIN _Job as j ON j.jobid = s.jobid
INNER JOIN _Subscribers as sub on sub.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
outer apply (

  select top 1
    jr1.JourneyName
  , jr1.JourneyID
  , jr1.VersionNumber
  , jr1.VersionID
  , ja1.ActivityID
  , ja1.ActivityName
  from (

      select
        convert(varchar(36), ja0.VersionID) as VersionID
      , convert(varchar(36), ja0.ActivityID) as ActivityID
      , ja0.ActivityName
      , ja0.ActivityExternalKey
      , ja0.JourneyActivityObjectID
      , ja0.ActivityType
      from _JourneyActivity as ja0
      where 1=1
      and convert(varchar(36),ja0.JourneyActivityObjectID) != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

  ) as ja1
  inner join (

    select
      convert(varchar(36), jr0.VersionID) as VersionID
    , convert(varchar(36), jr0.JourneyID) as JourneyID
    , jr0.JourneyName
    , jr0.VersionNumber
    , jr0.CreatedDate
    , jr0.LastPublishedDate
    , jr0.ModifiedDate
    , jr0.JourneyStatus
    from _Journey as jr0

  ) as jr1 on jr1.versionid = ja1.versionid
  where 1=1
  and ja1.JourneyActivityObjectID = j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
  order by jr1.versionNumber desc

) as jr
outer apply (
  select top 1
    o1.isunique
  , o1.eventDate
  from _Open as o1
  where 1=1
  and o1.JobID = s.JobID
  and o1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and o1.IsUnique = 1
  order by o1.eventDate desc
) as o
outer apply (
  select top 1
    c1.isunique
  , c1.eventDate
  from _Click as c1
  where 1=1
  and c1.JobID = s.JobID
  and c1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and c1.IsUnique = 1
  order by c1.eventDate desc
) as c
outer apply (
  select top 1
    u1.isunique
  , u1.eventDate
  from _Unsubscribe as u1
  where 1=1
  and u1.JobID = s.JobID
  and u1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and u1.IsUnique = 1
  order by u1.eventDate desc
) as u
outer apply (
  select top 1
    cmpl1.isunique
  , cmpl1.eventDate
  from _Complaint as cmpl1
  where 1=1
  and cmpl1.JobID = s.JobID
  and cmpl1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and cmpl1.IsUnique = 1
  order by cmpl1.eventDate desc
) as cmpl
outer apply (
  select top 1
    f1.isunique
  , f1.TransactionTime
  from _FTAF as f1
  where 1=1
  and f1.JobID = s.JobID
  and f1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and f1.IsUnique = 1
  order by f1.TransactionTime desc
) as f
outer apply (
  select top 1
    b1.isunique
  , b1.eventDate
  , b1.BounceCategory
  , b1.BounceSubcategory
  from _Bounce as b1
  where 1=1
  and b1.JobID  = s.JobID
  and b1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
  and b1.IsUnique = 1
  order by b1.eventDate desc
) as b

WHERE 1=1
AND LEN(s.SubscriberKey) = 18

I think you'll find this query will time out once your send volume increases. I like to split the queries by activity type.
